# Setting default locale for Tomcat Service in Windows XP

Tags: java, tomcat, service, locale

I have installed Apache Tomcat 6 as a Service in a Windows XP computer (French)

My problem is that Tomcat itself and all webapps (Sonar and Hudson) now show french messages.
I want English messages of course so I went to the "Regional Settings" window in Control panel and changed everything to English (US)

Tomcat however is **still** in French. Nothing changed at all.

I suspect that because it runs as a service it does not pick the settings from control panel.

So is there any way to trick the Tomcat JVM so that it uses English instead of French?
I have sys admin access to the machine (XP PRO French)

Thank you

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to set `user.language` and `user.region` appropriately,

e.g.

```
java -Duser.language=en -Duser.region=CA
```

in your Tomcat startup (probably `catalina.bat`). Check [this link](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/locale/) for more info, and for references to the sets of valid ISO codes for the above.

Comment: There is no catalina.bat since Apache is a service. I put them in the configuration GUI dialog. Also in order to work they have to be the first options in the java command line. Strange...

Comment: It worked for me to put only the -Duser.language=en in the Tomcat tray monitor (GUI), it was in the middle of other parameters (like -Xmx and so on) and it worked fine.

Comment: Actually it should be set in `setenv.bat` (or `setenv.sh` under linux). See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13164237/333296

Comment: Link is dead. I think it's here now : http://www.oracle.com/us/technologies/java/locale-140624.html You can check WayBackMachine : https://web.archive.org/web/20090806074321/http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/locale/

Answer (score 4):

The Tomcat manager was showing up in French for me, despite the fact that I tried some of the suggestions above.  The issue turned out to be browser specific.  Chrome had "French" listed as one of my languages and as soon as I removed it from the list in preferences and refreshed the page, Tomcat showed up in English.  I hope that will be helpful for anybody else in the future who is having this sort of problem.

Comment: Same situation and fix here. French wasn't even set to highest priority. Only removing it seems to work. Is French somehow preferred over other languages?

Answer (score 1):

Specify language option in service parameters.

$Tomcat/bin/javaw.exe move to Java tab and specify -Duser.language=en -Duser.region=CA at Java Options:

Answer (score 1):

Regional Settings are per user and services are run as a different user (which one is used for each service can be checked in Control Panel / Administrative Tools / Services ).

So you changed the settings for the user account you used to log in, while the Tomcat service is run under a different account.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, catalina.bat (or catalina.sh) is not executed by Windows when running Tomcat service, so catalina.bat modification doesn't solve this problem.

The solution is to run the service manually (or re-install the service) adding these parameters to the execution of the service. Here it's the specification of how the service must be run or installed in order to do this:

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html (Tomcat 6)
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html (Tomcat 7)

According to this specification, to run Tomcat6 service establishing en_US locale, you should execute:

```
> $PATH_TO_TOMCAT/bin/tomcat6.exe //TS//Tomcat6 ++JvmOptions -Duser.language=en;-Duser.region=US
```

In the link above, there are some examples of how to install and delete the service as well.

Hope this helps!