# UnsatisfiedLinkError with OpenCV in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, opencv, java-native-interface, spring-tool-suite

First of all, I have a basic example of OpenCV running in a main method.
However, if I use OpenCV in a Spring Web Controller, an error is thrown.

I am getting an UnsatisfiedLinkError when running the following code inside a **Tomcat** Server, within STS (Spring Tool Suite), and have boiled the problem down to the following code:

```
System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
CascadeClassifier cascadeClassifier = new CascadeClassifier();
```

The run configurations of both the server and the "main" application contain the VM Arguments pointing to the OpenCV DLLs:

```
-Djava.library.path="C:\opencv\build\java\x64;C:\opencv\build\x64\vc10\bin"
```

For reference, I have also included the pertinent bits of the stacktrace below:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed;
nested exception is
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.opencv.objdetect.CascadeClassifier.CascadeClassifier_0()J
...
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
org.opencv.objdetect.CascadeClassifier.CascadeClassifier_0()J
    at org.opencv.objdetect.CascadeClassifier.CascadeClassifier_0(Native Method)
    at org.opencv.objdetect.CascadeClassifier.<init>(CascadeClassifier.java:38)
    at com.immersion.test.controllers.SimpleController.createClassifier(SimpleController.java:19)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
```

Note: I have read in [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16449781/opencv-cascadeclassifier-error) StackOverflow threads that the main cause of the UnsatisfiedLinkError is the missing `System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME)` call. This is clearly not the case here, since it is being called just above where the exception is thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the default **run configuration** to start a Tomcat server within STS/Eclipse is essentially just a launcher for Tomcat.
This means that any VM Args that are added to the Tomcat 'run configuration' will not be transferred to the actual Tomcat instance.

On looking in  `tcruntime-instance.bat` within the Tomcat directory (this is what ends up creating the tomcat java instance), we can see that simply by adding our intended VM Args to the `JAVA_OPTS` environment variable, the dlls will be available to Tomcat.

**TL;DR:**

So.. Simply add the the locations of the OpenCV binaries to your `JAVA_OPTS` environment variable:

`-Djava.library.path="C:\opencv\build\java\x64;C:\opencv\build\x64\vc10\bin"`

For more information on setting JAVA_OPTS for Tomcat, see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13164115/appropriate-place-in-catalina-bat-to-set-java-opts).

Answer (score 2):

Same thing here.

I try what Dylan said, but did not work here.

But I added "C:\opencv\build\java\x64;C:\opencv\build\x64\vc10\bin" on my PATH variable. On my sys variables.

[image]

ps: I'm using windows.