# How to get OpenCv to work with Grails 3 using Intellij Idea?

Tags: grails, dependency-management, grails-3.1

I'm unable to get OpenCV to work with Grails. I have the following error:

```
no opencv_java2413 in java.library.path
```

I've installed the latest OpenCV (2.4.13) in "C:\opencv", and added the following Gradle dependency:

```
compile files('libs/opencv-2413.jar')
```

and edited the run configuration : 
[image]
but I still get the same error (tried to clean, rebuild ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GOT IT! Add a ton of logging to my vv.Hello.java class (IDK if this works with groovy or not)
What the HELL is the "files" directory?
Where did that come from GRAILS GURUS? 
I put my DLL in there & it just worked. haha. mine is the 310 yours will be 24x.

**EDIT**: Turns out the .dll has to be in BOTH, files dir & the system PATH. Add the sample code snippet to see where the locations are for your system (ie: if you're running jetty or something.) put the DLL in both. then run it. To get it to run from IntelliJ I had to drop the dll in this system dir:

`C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\`
and here: 
`user.dir=C:\grdev\hwopencv\files\`
see below. 
[GitHub sample of what I got working](https://github.com/kmacpher67/grails-opencv-sample)

https://github.com/kmacpher67/grails-opencv-sample/blob/master/README.md

My motto is: "When in doubt, log the crap of everything, till there's enough log files to crash the o/s and end the futility!"

`System.out.println("Welcome to OpenCV " + Core.VERSION);
        System.out.println("Welcome to OpenCV NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME= " + Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
        String opencvpath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\files\\";
        System.out.println("user.dir="+opencvpath);
        String libPath = System.getProperty("java.library.path");
        System.out.println("libPath="+libPath);
        System.load(opencvpath + Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME + ".dll");`

I got a love-hate relationship with libs. When they do magic for you, love them! When they do this to me. 
Thanks for motivating me to figure this out!

**NOTE2**: I got this working from groovy too! Use a different static loader syntax (see sample controller method index1
`Runtime.getRuntime().load0(groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.class, path)`

Comment: deleted my stupid question ^^' thanks a lot for your help I will try it and give you a feedback

Comment: why was it stupid, i figure it it out. the problem is the loading of the DLL it has to be in both the lib path & files directory.

Comment: i'm stil getting the same errors, I've put the dll in my projectRoot/files and jar + dll (as you did :D)  in projectRoot/libs, check the link for the code and the stackTrace : http://pastie.org/10852062

Comment: Yeah, I had same problem with the IDEA IntellJ grails command, I ended up finding out this! You need it in the PATH & the files directory. 
copy the .DLL to here: ```C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0```
or try
````set PATH=%PATH%;C:\opencv\build\java\x64
grails run-app````

Comment: Also, debug it from the command line first.  I don't know why but the DLL has to be in both the "path" and files directory.  It's likely some strange grails-spring-tomcat deploy craziness.

Comment: opencv folks really need to publish this as a maven pom, it would be super cool to have this as a plug-in.

Comment: yes they do :/ trying to add dll folder to the PATH , putting it in the path you gave me didn't solve the problem :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112930/discussion-between-saywow-and-ken).

Comment: I wonder what is the equivalent of `System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\files\\"` in Grails 2.

Answer (score 0):

It's not finding the jar file maybe?  I'm a pro at breaking builds that way, can you try putting it as absolute instead of relative paths?

`compile files('c:/opencv/libs/opencv-2413.jar')`

BTW: Did you follow any specific guide or recipe for this? 
I was hoping there was a simple plug-in already completed that had this as a service using Event Handling or something, these can be non-deterministic long running processes, not ideal for web page response times. 
EDIT TO ADD IMAGE: 
So I d/l the 3.1 version. It's like the grails 2x vs 3.x decision, I've used both and I think the 3.x has more features and is definitely stable enough. Like grails, there's crap ton of 2.x folks out there. 
Use IDEA Import Eclipse project. 
They have an "ant" sample which is not gradle or grails, but basic java version working suggests this is either a class path or .dll source path issue. 
I'm going to try building a simple HW grails sample see if I can get it to compile.  Were you able to get a basic java only sample to work?
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, if the jar wasn't find I wouldn't be able to import libs, the jar is working but the dll file isn't found, I followed this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BrR6MFhyNEA and I found many answers about my problem in stackOverFlow but none of them worked in my case (the answers were for IntellijIdea but not Grails)

Comment: BTW: As I thought more about this I got to thinking about mvn pom repos for the dependency... well, not the first. Didn't read all the details yet. but it looks like this has been done before. 
[link]http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/nu.pattern/opencv/2.4.9-4

[link]http://answers.opencv.org/question/30945/why-isnt-the-opencv-java-libraries-available-via-maven/

[link]http://code.opencv.org/issues/3097

Comment: Blind leading the blind here, but where is the /libs folder directory in grails 3? 
Did you try the old When you add or remove jar files in lib you need to run

grails compile --refresh-dependencies
in order to get Grails to notice the changes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, if the lib wasn't imported, am I not supposed to get errors when I try to import opencv's classes from my services? and yes I have the jar in my projectRoot/libs, the problem here is with dll

Comment: I'm with you, this is not the answer, I thank you for the question!
I got the same situation with opencv 3.x it's not loading dll. when I run this from a simple java program console, IDEA does this: 
````-Djava.library.path=C:\opencv\build\java\x64````
I got the same thing when trying to call the code from groovy, I'm trying to load it from actual java class. of course, grails is running from a tomcat container.

Comment: lol sorry, I meant thank you for writing this :) and thank you for taking time and testing this for me, please let me know if you find any solution

Comment: I moved it to a java class thinking it was a .dll classloader issue, which this is but NOT for the java class, but for the C++ native linked library. 
Around line 25 of Hello.java - 
Same error which works fine from the sample code. 
````25:        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);````
Our problem is loading the external libs into tomcat servlet container engine. google tomcat opencv... 
I'm looking at loading this way 
````
    static {
        String path = "./libs/opencv_java310.dll";
        System.load(path);
    }
```

Comment: I found this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21794703/unsatisfiedlinkerror-with-opencv-in-tomcat  I haven't try it yet, and I've already seen this static thing but didn't get it and didn't work within my groovy class (maybe I've done something wrong)

Comment: welp, back to my real job: are you getting a 
```` Class
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError``` 
at a similar style that I'm showing above?

Comment: I had just read that one when you posted it! haha. did that from a command line, tried JAVA_OPTS, etc, then I found a guy recommending you dump the system vars and BAM!  the files directory! stupid grails.