# Force tomcat to return response in English

Tags: tomcat, locale, response

The title says it all, how can I force Tomcat to return responses in English language? I am sending http requests to the tomcat manager and it returns responses like:

```
OK - Deployed application at context path /foo
```

or

```
FAIL - Failed to start .... bla bla
```

But when I try to run the application for example on a french OS it is returning the responses in french, and I don't want that. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

A quick search suggests that it is possible to change the default locale for tomcat: [Setting default locale for Tomcat Service in Windows XP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153521/setting-default-locale-for-tomcat-service-in-windows-xp)

Comment: OK! but how can I do it within my application?

Comment: That depends on the framework of your application, but a general java way would be Locale.setDefault(new Locale(...));